# Why does FFmpeg's stream_loop option add a pause?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have tested several files with the added option

```
-fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1
```

to make them loop, but all have a slight pause just before they loop (250 ms or so). The loop filter does not have this issue, but it has other issues.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing this for audio loops

Comment: See comments below, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with stream_loop. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5719

Wrapping to MKV or TS and then looping *may* work. Re-encoding your video as intraframe is the safest option.

Comment: Wow, reported 11 months ago already and it's still there.. Re-encoding is not an option for me unfortunately, clients have pre-made loops.

Comment: Do you intend to 'live-stream' the looped output?

Comment: It is processed live, so I guess that is a 'yes'. So it's not possible to cut out pauses, if that's where you're heading..

Comment: BTW: wrapping in ts (no difference) or mkv (shorter pause) is no fix either. Neither is re-encoding to intraframe. The very visible pause remains present.

Comment: Strange. Can you upload your sample?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YATlG4DeOdd0RURUNJUG9mVFE
Note visually this is not a loop, this is just something to test audio sync.

Comment: Before I check this further, let me confirm that in the original file, the flash of the black box happens when the OSD says 1:52:12 and the beep happens at 1:52:16

Comment: I have no idea, someone else made this file. It's just a loop someone whipped up for me a long time ago to check for obvious issues. Served me well to find this issue and of all videos I have this is  nice and small.

Comment: Ok, but when you play it, is the timing of the beep like I see it?

Comment: I don't see why this is relevant to the issue at hand, but I checked in VirtualDub and audio is 3 frames late. So the first beep is at 1:52:15.

Comment: I'm checking if the timestamps or stream frame order is wonky. In a video editor, I get the beep at 1:52:13. What the stream_loop bugs relates to, is generating continuous timestamps, but stream quirks can affect this.

Comment: Just so you know I can reproduce the bug with lots of videos, all from different sources.
Interesting about your editor. I have always used VirtualDub as a reference, this is the first time I have any reason to doubt.

Comment: I wonder if converting it to uncompressed A+V or even separate images and sound track would overcome the bug? Have you tried anything with the sample I uploaded for you? I don't think they will ever fix this btw.

Comment: Images will work as there is a dedicated loop option (and code): `-loop 1`

Comment: I'll look into your sample sometime during the next few days.

Comment: Yeah, but the documentation is lacking and I get the idea it is just for images, not audio. Remember the loop filter already works fine for just video, it's when audio needs to be included that issues start to happen.
Oh, I just get a warning that we're apparently not supposed to use comments for discussions and we need to move this to chat.

Comment: Any updates? I have pause about 15-20seconds between loops. That's disgusting

Comment: Are you using current version of ffmpeg? The ticket is marked as fixed in Nov '17.

Comment: Working for me in latest version of FFMPEG. Doesn't work with the version packaged with Ubuntu 18.04 currently (3.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

I am streaming a looping video and was struggling with pauses in-between loops too. What I discovered was that I was streaming at 24 FPS, but my input video was 23.97. Re-encoding the video at 24 FPS with the FPS filter `fps=fps=24` resolved the issue.

See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate for more information on changing the frame rate with FFmpeg.